# Cannot save imageUrl in UIViewController in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have saved annotation in core data, and I have gotten imageUrl from Flickr. But I can’t save imageUrls in core data. There is my code

```
func loadPhotos(pageNumber: Int) {
    GetImageUrls.sharedInstance.getImageUrls(pageNumber: pageNumber){(success, photosUrl, error) in
        if success {

            for url in photosUrl! {
                let photo = Album(location: self.tappedPinLocation!, imageUrl: url, context: self.stack.context)
                print("photo is \(photo)")
            }
            do {
                try self.stack.context.save()
            } catch {
                print("Error saving the url")
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.albumCollection.reloadData()
            }

        } else {
            print("Error loading photos")
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my project with “do-catch” syntax, I got “Error saving the url”, I don’t know why?
My project is on FixCoredataError branch. Please help me. https://github.com/MartinSnow/MyVirtualTourist.git

Comment: what does the error specifically say? “Error saving the url” ? can you show the error if possible?

Comment: Forgive me, I posted the wrong code before. 
Actually, the project run with no error. What confuse me is that when implement "do-catch" syntax such as 
    do {
              try self.stack.context.save()
          } catch {
              print("Error saving the url")
          }
"try self.stack.context.save()" doesn't be implemented, but print("Error saving the url") in debug area.

Comment: It depends on what happens on the line reading `let photo = Album(...)` In that method you're doing something Core Data doesn't like. There's no way to tell what that is without seeing that code.